# Soundcloud Custom Player Pause Player

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundcloud

How do you pause the Soundcloud Custom Player (http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/custom-player)? I have a large single page with audio players.  When a user navigates to a different section of the page the hash in the URL changes.  How do I pause the Soundcloud Custom Player when the hash changes?

I've tried `$(".sc-player").pause()` but it doesn't always work.  I'm looking for it to work on desktop and mobile.  It seems desktop uses a hidden SWF file while mobile uses the audio element.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: do you have an example of your page? If you have multiple audio players on the page, $(".sc-player").pause() might not work as you may be targeting multiple instances of the audio player. In terms of pausing when the hash changes, have you tried storing current URL in a JS variable and monitoring it for changes?

Comment: I think I can listen to the hashchange event, but is there any other way to stop/pause the audio player?  Is there a stopAll() method?

Comment: Not too sure... If you wanted to pause all the players and there's no method available to do so, you could always just iterate through them one by one : $(".sc-player").each(function() { $(this).pause(); });

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.sc-player.playing a.sc-pause').click();
```

Answer (score 1):

I kind of discovered this by accident (tested on the jsFiddle page, and it paused the player).

To the code on this page I made a little addition:
http://jsfiddle.net/aj3Pw/1/

In the HTML, I added a 'Pause' button:

```
<button id="pause">Pause</button>
```

and then at the bottom of the JS, I added an event listener with "sc.pause()", and it worked:

```
document.getElementById('pause').addEventListener('click', function() { sc.pause();
```

Hope this helps!